# Writing String to an rtf in java doesn't keep structure

Tags: java, string, rtf, file-writing

I wrote a FileMerge class where I take an rtf and replace certain tags with SQL data. 
Everything is ok but one part in which I replace one tag with one or more lines, it replaces the file but \n or \r\n doesn't create a new line when opened in word.

the code:

```
String otherFamilyString="\n";


    for(int i=0;i<OtherFamily.size();i=i+TotalArguments)
    {
        otherFamilyString +=  "\n"+OtherFamily.get(i+FamilyMbrId) +"|\t"+ OtherFamily.get(i+FamilyMbrName) +"|\t"+ OtherFamily.get(i+FamilyStatus)+"|\t"
        + OtherFamily.get(i+FamilyCoveragetype) +"|  "+ OtherFamily.get(i+FamilyRelationship) +"|" ;
        System.out.print(i+" "+otherFamilyString);


    }
    newtext = newtext.replaceAll("OTHERFAMILY",otherFamilyString);



    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(outPutDir+memberInfo.get(GroupId).replace(" ", "")+newName.replace("*", "")); 
    writer.write(newtext);//write the new file 
    writer.close();
```

I also tried System.getProperty("line.separator") unsuccessfully.

When I open the file in notepad, I can see that all of the code is in rich text except this part which shows in the right structure.
I think I need a  way to write this string in rich text format so it will show good in word.

Thank you for the help,
Idan.

Comment: Post a sample of the RTF you expect vs. whatyou get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In RTF, line breaks are not indicated by a new line in the text - instead, you must use the right control sequence to do this. From skimming over [the specification](http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/RTF-Spec-1.0.txt), `\line` looks like a hard line break, and `\par` like a paragraph break.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but know when I use "\\line" in console it shows \line but when writing to the file it only writes line without the backslash

Comment: Have a look at the produced file (open it with a plain text editor, nothing which understands RFT). Do you see the `\line` there? (You will have to write `"\\line"` in a Java string, probably.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is some documentation pertaining to the RTF format: http://search.cpan.org/~sburke/RTF-Writer/lib/RTF/Cookbook.pod#RTF_Document_Structure

It says to specify a newline using a `\line` command.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but know when I use "\\line" in console it shows \line but when writing to the file it only writes line without the backslash.